How to get a correct JSON response to a POST request in Delphi?
My program accesses the local Nitro server (API Jan for Windows - https://jan.ai/api-reference#tag/chat/post/chat/completions). I'm trying to write a POST request for the "Create chat completion" API request. This is communication with the AI model.
Everything works fine in Python and I get the answer. In Delphi 11.3, I get some strange blocks instead of response. But they contain the necessary data (each block contains 1 word). Although I have to receive the JSON and highlight the response in a "content" object.
Here is my code:
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  RequestData: TStringStream;
  ResponseData: string;
  JsonResponse: TJSONObject;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  RequestData := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    RequestData.WriteString('{"messages":[{"content":"You are a helpful assistant.","role":"system"},{"content":"How are you?","role":"user"}],"model":'+
    '"tinyllama-1.1b","stream":true,"max_tokens":2048,"stop":["hello","Hello","HELLO","hELLO"],"frequency_penalty":0,"presence_penalty":0,"temperature":0.7,"top_p":0.95}');
    ResponseData := IdHTTP.Post('http://localhost:1337/v1/chat/completions', RequestData);
    Memo2.Lines.Add(ResponseData);
    JsonResponse := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(ResponseData) as TJSONObject;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
    RequestData.Free;
  end;
end;

I sent an array, stream, HTTP 200 response OK, but this is the best I could get. Unfortunately, I can’t send screenshots, but the HTTP analyzer for Delphi and the code for Python work correctly, but the answer in Delphi is not JSON.
[![image][1]][1]
Here is a valid Python query that works in my case:
import requests

url = "http://localhost:1337/v1/chat/completions"

payload = {
    "messages": [
        {
            "content": "You are a helpful assistant.",
            "role": "system"
        },
        {
            "content": "Hello!",
            "role": "user"
        }
    ],
    "model": "tinyllama-1.1b",
    "stream": True,
    "max_tokens": 2048,
    "stop": ["hello", "Hello", "HELLO", "hELLO"],
    "frequency_penalty": 0,
    "presence_penalty": 0,
    "temperature": 0.7,
    "top_p": 0.95
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.json())

And I get this correct answer. But in Delphi the answer is as in the screenshot.
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": null,
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "content": "Hello user. What can I help you with?",
        "role": "assistant"
      }
    }
  ],
  "created": 1700193928,
  "id": "ebwd2niJvJB1Q2Whyvkz",
  "model": "_",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "system_fingerprint": "_",
  "usage": {
    "completion_tokens": 500,
    "prompt_tokens": 33,
    "total_tokens": 533
  }
}


@AmigoJack "Access IdHTTP.ResponseText for the payload" - that is absolutely wrong. That will return the status text (ie OK for a 200), not the payload. The code is receiving the payload correctly. It is just not the payload the OP is expecting. That is a server-side issue.

Since the posted request payloads are functionally identical in both cases, the problem has to be something else that is different between the Delphi request and the Python request. For example, perhaps the server reacts differently depending on the request User-Agent header. A lot of servers don't like Indy's default UserAgent value. Try setting IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent to the same value that Python (or any web browser) sends.

@RemyLebeau Sorry, I just assumed. Makes sense.

Since the response JSON contains "object": "chat.completion.chunk": the docs define: "Returns a chat completion object, or a streamed sequence of chat completion chunk objects if the request is streamed." However, I don't find what triggers either. But both outcomes are explained (and, look logically quite easy to be merged).

Thanks everyone for your ideas. Without them, I wouldn't check that there are two correct server responses, of which only one works for me.

@AntonTretyak this is a Q&A site. Don't edit the question to provide an answer. See Can I answer my own question. Please fix it by moving your edit into an actual answer. Thanks.

Thank you all very much for your answers. I decided to see what could influence the result. It turns out that I was getting the correct answer. This is confirmed by the server's internal request debugger. But! I had a parameter set in the RequestData.WriteString "stream":true. When I changed it to "stream":false I got the correct JSON for my case
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  RequestData: TStringStream;
  ResponseData: string;
  JsonResponse: TJSONObject;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  RequestData := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    RequestData.WriteString('{"messages":[{"content":"You are a helpful assistant.","role":"system"},{"content":"How are you?","role":"user"}],"model":'+
    '"tinyllama-1.1b","stream":false,"max_tokens":2048,"stop":["hello","Hello","HELLO","hELLO"],"frequency_penalty":0,"presence_penalty":0,"temperature":0.7,"top_p":0.95}');
    ResponseData := IdHTTP.Post('http://localhost:1337/v1/chat/completions', RequestData);
    Memo2.Lines.Add(ResponseData);
    JsonResponse := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(ResponseData) as TJSONObject;
      try
        Memo1.Lines.Add(JsonResponse.FindValue('choices[0].message.content').Value);
      finally
        JsonResponse.Free;
      end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
    RequestData.Free;
  end;
end;

Now everything works as it should and I can integrate AI into my Delphi program. Thank you all very much!

